chrome.downloads API: Replace invalid characters in filename with regex
I am trying to download files with the chrome.downloads.download(...). The filename is given externally, so I don't know the characters inside. If it contains invalid characters, the function download will throw an error Error: Invalid filename.

Is there a regex in JavaScript that replaces all and only the invalid starting/middle/ending Unicode characters with _ in the filename?

Or is there a documentation listing the rules for a filename in Chrome?

Is there a way to make Chrome replace invalid characters in my filename, instead of throwing an error?


Chrome disallows more characters than common filesystems (e.g. NTFS), and I am not sure the exact definition of "invalid character" by Chrome. My current regex attempt is
var regex = /^\.|\.$|[\x00-\x1f\\\/:*?"<>|\r\n\u200D]/g;
filename.replaceAll(regex, '_');

But it only covers a few of the invalid Unicode characters.
I avoid using the <a> method to download (i.e. create <a> with href and download attributes, then click on it), because I would like to create subdirectries in the downloads folder.

Regex matching all and only invalid Unicode characters / filenames
If the filename contains some invalid Unicode characters, or matches a reserved keyword in NTFS, then chrome.downloads.download will throw Error: Invalid filename.

At any position (start/middle/end), the following Unicode characters are invalid:

Control characters \p{Cc} (\u{0} is allowed at the middle)
: ? " * < > | ~ (NTFS reserved characters)
\ and / (NTFS & Chrome treat them as path separators instead of a character in filename, so Invalid filename error will NOT occur)
Format characters \p{Cf}
Non-characters \p{Cn}

Zero-width joiner \u{200D} is commonly used to composite emojis and form a new emoji. However, this character is invalid as well, as its category is "Format characters".
The regex is /[:?"*<>|~/\\\u{1}-\u{1f}\u{7f}\u{80}-\u{9f}\p{Cf}\p{Cn}]/gu

At the start/end of filename, the following Unicode characters are invalid:

NUL character \u{0}
Line separator \p{Zl}
Paragraph separator \p{Zp}
Space separators \p{Zs}
A dot . (rule by NTFS)

The regex is /^[.\u{0}\p{Zl}\p{Zp}\p{Zs}]|[.\u{0}\p{Zl}\p{Zp}\p{Zs}]$/gu

Reserved keywords in NTFS: Filenames of CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, LPT9 (case-insensitive), with or without file extension, are all invalid.
The regex is /^(CON|PRN|AUX|NUL|COM[1-9]|LPT[1-9])(?=\.|$)/gui


Other categories of Unicode characters, including private-use \p{Co} and surrogate pairs \p{Cs}, are allowed at any position.
Final regex (for JavaScript):
var pattern = /[:?"*<>|~/\\\u{1}-\u{1f}\u{7f}\u{80}-\u{9f}\p{Cf}\p{Cn}]|^[.\u{0}\p{Zl}\p{Zp}\p{Zs}]|[.\u{0}\p{Zl}\p{Zp}\p{Zs}]$|^(CON|PRN|AUX|NUL|COM[1-9]|LPT[1-9])(?=\.|$)/gui;
filename.replaceAll(pattern, '_');

Note: These characters/filenames are also invalid in NTFS, but sometimes NTFS just deletes the character instead of displaying an error.

How to Determine the invalid Unicode characters
I wrote a script to try each Unicode character, and ran it on Google Chrome 126.0.6478.116 on Windows 11 23H2 22631.3737.
What the script does:

Call serviceWorker.postMessage('') in SW console to start/stop the for loop
Create an empty blob and an Object URL to the blob in offscreen document
Call chrome.downloads.download, pass the Unicode character as filename and the URL created
Try to catch Error: Invalid filename. The character is invalid if error caught, otherwise valid.
Store the result in chrome.storage.local
Clear the download history periodically to maintain performance

The invalid Unicode characters at the start/end are found. Within the set, some characters are invalid at the middle of a filename as well. So we run the script again, replacing filename: char with
filename: `0${char}0`

background.js:
var creating;

async function setup_offscreen_document() {
    const offscreenUrl = chrome.runtime.getURL("offscreen.html");
    const existingContexts = await chrome.runtime.getContexts({
        contextTypes: ['OFFSCREEN_DOCUMENT'],
        documentUrls: [offscreenUrl]
    });

    if (existingContexts.length > 0) {
        return;
    }

    if (creating) {
        await creating;
    } else {
        creating = chrome.offscreen.createDocument({
            url: "offscreen.html",
            reasons: ['BLOBS'],
            justification: 'Create object URLs',
        });
        await creating;
        creating = null;
    }
}

var stop = true;
var url;

async function test(code) {
    var char = String.fromCodePoint(code);
    try {
        chrome.downloads.cancel(await chrome.downloads.download({ url: url, filename: char }));
        chrome.storage.local.set({ [code]: { char: char, invalid: false } });
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.message == "Invalid filename")
            chrome.storage.local.set({ [code]: { char: char, invalid: true } });
        else
            throw error;
    }
}

async function loop() {
    await setup_offscreen_document();
    url = await chrome.runtime.sendMessage(undefined, {});
    var start = (await chrome.storage.local.get('last'))['last'];
    if (start == undefined)
        start = 0;
    for (var i = start + 1; i <= 0x10ffff; i++) {
        await test(i);
        await chrome.storage.local.set({ last: i });
        if ((i - start) % 10000 == 0)
            chrome.browsingData.removeDownloads({});
        if (stop)
            break;
    }
}

function start_loop() {
    stop = false;
    loop();
}

function stop_loop() {
    stop = true;
}

self.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    if (stop)
        start_loop();
    else
        stop_loop();
});

manifest.json:
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Unicode Test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Test.",
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js",
        "type": "module"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "downloads",
        "storage",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "offscreen",
        "browsingData"
    ]
}


I'm not sure about the rules for a filename in Chrome, I found this developer documentation style guide, but a simple solution would be to only accept alphanumeric characters, the minus and the period, with the regex:
var regex = /[^\w-.]/g;

If there are many invalid characters, perhaps it is more convenient to delete them rather than replace them with an underscore character:
filename.replaceAll(regex, '');

If you want to keep accented characters in filenames (although this is not recommended for filenames), you can exclude them too by adding them to the regex inside the square brackets, looking at this answer.
